# Compare 3 arrays and find common elements between 2 and 3 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have theses  arrays

And I want to compare and find the element at least repeated in two of these arrays

This is the function that I return common elements between 3 arrays
But now I want to return the common elements between 2 arrays of these arrays + 3 common elements in them.

```
var buyArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < fiveBuy.length; i++) {
    const e = fiveBuy[i];
      for (let j = 0; j < fifteenBuy.length; j++) {
        const el = fifteenBuy[j];
        for (let k = 0; k < thirtyBuy.length; k++) {
            const ele = thirtyBuy[k];
            if(e == el && e == ele){
              buyArray.push(e);
            }
        }        
      }
  }
```

Comment: Why is f.e. `41` not in your desired result? That was contained in your first and third array.

Comment: You don't need to consider _"3 common elements"_. If an element is in 3 lists, it's also in 2 lists. Why is `2` in your result? It's only in the first list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a one-liner solution:

```js
let fiveBuy = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 41];
let fifteenBuy = [1, 4, 3, 0, 99, 10, 23];
let thirtyBuy = [3, 41, 1, 0, 10, 23];

const findCommon = (min, ...arrs) => [...new Set(arrs.flat())].filter(e => arrs.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur.includes(e), 0) >= min);

// the first argument is the minimum arrays an element has to be appearing
console.log(findCommon(2, fiveBuy, fifteenBuy, thirtyBuy));
```